# Javascript form submission error

Tags: javascript, html

Am having problems with my code when submitting to a form.  If nothing is entered in the textbox, then the correct error comes up, but when there are valid entries for the Radio Button responses, it still displays an error saying 'Please select a score' and such like when there is a score selected.

I can't seem to see what I have entered wrong.

All the best

CP

```
<form name="promoForm2" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action=reactsubmit.php onSubmit="return validateForm();">
<ul class=mainForm id="mainForm_1">

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>

function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["promoForm2"]["DJcomment"].value; 
    if (x==null || x=="") 
    { 
        alert("Please enter a comment."); 
        return false; 
    }  

    var x=document.forms["promoForm2"]["score"].value; 
    if (x==null || x=="") 
    { 
        alert("Please enter a score for the track."); 
        return false; 
    } 

    var x=document.forms["promoForm2"]["FavMix"].value; 
    if (x==null || x=="") 
    { 
        alert("Please select your favourite mix."); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
</SCRIPT>

<table border='0'><tr><td>Support: </td><td><input type="radio" name="DJsupport" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" name="DJsupport" value="No">No</td></tr>

<tr><td>Favourite Mix: </td><td><input type="radio" name="FavMix" value="Enemy (Original Mix)">Enemy (Original Mix)</td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="FavMix" value="Enemy (Original Mix)">Enemy (Original Mix)</td></tr>

<tr><td></td></tr><tr><td>Score: </td><td><input type="radio" name="score" value="1">1<input type="radio" name="score" value="2">2<input type="radio" name="score" value="3">3<input type="radio" name="score" value="4">4<input type="radio" name="score" value="5">5<input type="radio" name="score" value="6">6<input type="radio" name="score" value="7">7<input type="radio" name="score" value="8">8<input type="radio" name="score" value="9">9<input type="radio" name="score" value="10">10<td></tr><tr><td>Comment: (Required) </td><td><textarea name="DJcomment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><p class="mainForm"><input id="saveForm" class="mainForm" type="submit" value="Submit Reaction" /></td></tr></li></form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the value of your radio buttons check their `checked` properties.

You'll need to check all radio buttons of a certain name in order to determine whether one was selected for its group.

```
function checkRadios(group) {
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        if (group[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function validateForm() {
    var x=document.forms["promoForm2"]["DJcomment"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please enter a comment.");
        return false;
    }

    if (!checkRadios(document.forms["promoForm2"]["score"])) {
        alert("Please enter a score for the track.");
        return false;
    }

    if (!checkRadios(document.forms["promoForm2"]["FavMix"])) {
        alert("Please select your favourite mix.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Live demonstration [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ap6hhmla).

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly!  I had to edit it to fit the last value in about whether the person Supported it but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms["promoForm2"]["score"]` is an array of input elements that you will need to iterate through to check if any one is checked.

```
var x=document.forms["promoForm2"]["FavMix"]; 
var pass=false;
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if (x[i].checked==true) { 
        pass=true;
        break;
    } 
}
if(pass==false){
    alert("Please select your favourite mix."); 
    return false;
}
```

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/nQrhR/).